# What is the meaning of “$YX\wedge$” (from a 1942 article)?

Tags: measure-theory, notation

In this article

http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183505105

what is the meaning of the notation $YX\wedge$, that is what does it mean when you write the notations for two sets together side by side? Is it intersection? Or the image under the multiplication map?

Comment: It looks like $YX$ just means $\{yx\mid y\in Y, x\in X\}$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Getting another question off the unanswered list.)

It is intersection.

In that paper we have a closed interval $I$ and a numerically valued measurable function $f$ on $I$. For $X\subseteq I$ the notation $X^\land$ is defined to be $f[X]=\{f(x):x\in X\}$, and for $Y\subseteq f[I]$ the notation $Y^\lor$ is defined to be $f^{-1}[Y]=\{x\in I:f(x)\in Y\}$. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ and $\prod_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ are what we would write $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty X_n$, respectively.

As for the specific expression $YX^\land$, for $X\subseteq I$ and $Y\subseteq f[I]$ the identity $YX^\land=\left(Y^\lor X\right)^\land$ is $$Y\cap f[X]=f\left[f^{-1}[Y]\cap X\right]$$ in modern notation.